# Accessing the method from another class in java

Tags: java

I have added Checkgateway class (converted has jar)to the build path of another class verifyLogin

```
public class Checkgateway {
    public static void GetDetail(String n) {
        final File plugin_list = new File("C:\\Users\\RajendraPrasadH\\eclipse-workspace\\Gateway\\src\\config.cfg");
    
            PluginLoader.parseConfig(plugin_list, null);
}
```

I need to access GetDetail() method in verifyLogin.java without extending this class but importing this class can be done.Is there any method to use GetDetail() method in verifyLogin.java without extending Checkgateway class.

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names and method names should always be written in camelCase, and class names in PascalCase. For instance, `GetDetail` should be `getDetail`, `plugin_list` should be `pluginList`, and `verifyLogin` should be `VerifyLogin`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `GetDetail(String n)` is not an instance method, so yo can import the class in the top of the `verifyLogin.java` class like `import thePathOfTheClass.CheckGateway`, and then you can call the method like `Checkgateway.GetDetail("Example")`

Answer (score 0):

I may not have get your question correctly, but by importing

1. you can directly call static method on class names

   Checkgateway.GetDetail("Example")
2. Or instance methods by instantiating class and calling method on instance

   Checkgateway gateway = new Checkgateway();

   gateway.GetDetail("Example"); //in case GetDetails is an instance method

Comment: But using both the methods the method is not running.Like in this method it will change the contents of the file but the contents of the file is unchanged.

Comment: if you can provide your complete code it will help to understand where you are facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The method getDetail() is static

In the Java programming language, the keyword static indicates that the particular member belongs to a type itself, rather than to an instance of that type. This means that only one instance of that static member is created which is shared across all instances of the class.

You should remove static keyword as , from what I can tell from your example you don't need all the instances of CheckGateWay to share the same instance of the member function.

After you do this import the class `import. … . … .CheckGateway` on the top of your `verifyLogin.java` file.

Create a new instance of the class in verifyLogin.java. i.e `CheckGateWay chkGateWay = new CheckGateWay();`

Then just call the method ex. `chkGateWay.getDetail("String");`

Hope this helps.